# FTP method keeps failing on a particular box, but works on another box

Tags: c#

I have two Win7 boxes on the same network. These boxes need to FTP certain files from a server within the same network. I have a long script which implements an FTP method.

Box 1 - Code works normally, absolutely no problems encountered.

Box 2 - Code breaks as soon as FTP method is encountered ( Exception is caught and an error box is shown. So i know exactly where the code breaks). Not sure what the issue is. I thought maybe something settings are wrong. But I am able to login to the server via command line and FTP the files via command line.

Definitely not a problem with the code. Both boxes have same versions of the code. Tried comparing firewall and IIS settings on the two boxes and everything looks ok. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is antivirus on both machines identical?  Are both 32-bit/64-bit? May I assume that you are using the FTP library built-into .net and not an exernal lib?

Comment: Both are 64 bit, and the FTP class is inbuilt into the code. I feel it can't be the code, as it works perfectly fine on the other sister box. Antivirus i am not sure?

Comment: Identical code doesn't necessarily mean identical external libraries or identical .NET with identical SP (just sayin). How about putting a try/catch block around the FTP code and show/log the exception (and any inner exceptions).

Comment: Yup i do have a try catch block for all the methods i have used. And error is right when I call my FTP.From method.

Comment: What do the error messages say (and inner exceptions)?

Comment: I call the method twice, as I need to FTP two different files. So each time I call it, I have a try-catch and a pop box to the user which tells him which file was not transferred in case of error. That way he can call helpdesk and specify which file was not transferred.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. We decided to clone the problematic box with an image of the box that works alright. Everything is fine for now, need to find the root cause of the problematic box later on.